# Appending a C-array to a vector in reverse order in C++98/03 without a for-loop

Tags: c++, vector

Its pretty straightforward to append a C-array to a vector (in C++ 98/03) like so:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
const int array[5] = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5};

vec.insert( vec.end() , array , array + 5 );
```

Is there a way to append the array to a vector *in reverse order* in C++98/03 without writing a for-loop. (Here's looking at you Sean Parent.)

Comment: [Reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) the array first?

Comment: Array is a constant. I'll modify the question to reflect that.

Comment: Also, technically it's not going to be possible without any loops. There has to be a loop *somewhere* even if you do not have it yourself (for example in the `insert` function you call).

Comment: Agreed. If you use an algorithm, it will most likely have a loop under the covers. The main (only) differences will be that it may look neater and will _probably_ be more efficient than you can do yourself. The complexity will be the same though.

Comment: I know there's got to be a for loop *somewhere*. The point Scott Parent was making is to use the standard library to do many of the things for which we write for-loops.

Comment: There never *has* to be a loop. Any loop is implementable as a recursive function instead. Of course this is not terribly important, because who cares which one it is. But I think it's fair to be nitpicky in response to a point that starts with "technically".

Comment: Waiting for some abuses from the community... :-) If you are stuck in C++98/03 then don't even bother to write such code. Don't even bother to learn/read C++. Just move to other programming languages. If you are getting upgraded to c++11 at least, then it's a different matter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There you go. Use [`std::reverse_copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse_copy/) with `std::back_inserter` to add elements to the vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int array[5] = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5};

std::reverse_copy(array , array + 5, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

If you're concerned about performance, don't forget to [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before copying.

Comment: Note that the other answer with `vector::insert` may lead to better code, since the container can judge the capacity that will be required by the full insertion more easily

Comment: @KABoissonneault How about calling [`vec.reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before copying?

Comment: Then you'd be making your answer less straightforward than the other one :P. But at the same time, with `vector::reserve` at least you'd be _guaranteed_ by the standard that there won't be pointless reallocations, while it's only _assumed_ to be done on `vector::insert`

Comment: `reserve` should only be used with great caution and should not be blindly recommended. If I make this into a function `f` and call it multiple times on the same vector, `reserve`ing inside `f` before each `reverse_copy` would be a significant pessimization by disabling the exponential growth.

Comment: @T.C. I don't disagree with you. The only reason I put the reserve thing is because people were nagging about it. Now after I put it, you tell me about a special case for which it's a bad idea. Sorry to you all, but this is C++, not python or ruby. One has to know what they're doing. So unless I have to extend my answer to 3 paragraphs explaining when to or not to use reserve, let's just assume that the user is going to read the documentation in the link I provided to understand the purpose. And btw, because I agree with you I didn't put it in the code, but in a statement after the code ;)

Comment: I see `reserve` as the special case (for when you know the final size of the vector and it will not grow beyond that), and in the general case you should simply let the usual exponential growth algorithm do its job (or use ranged insert). It's certainly not something to be recommended whenever "you're concerned about performance" - who using C++ doesn't?

Comment: @T.C. For me, I sure know all these details. I can't, however, imagine how a beginner might think. Please suggest an edit that's a compromise between your advice and others' performance concern.

Comment: The simple and correct resolution of the performance concern of "others" (I see only one person) is "use range insert with reverse iterators". Constrained to use `reverse_copy`, the answer is "that's the price you pay, but in some special cases it can be alleviated with appropriate uses of `reserve`". If targeting beginners, I would even end it before the "but" and not mention `reserve` at all.

Comment: @T.C. No, it's not one person. Check the other answer's comments. Now I'm starting to disagree with you. There's absolutely no difference between reserve + push_back vs insert, everyone should know that. You mentioning "insert" is absolutely pointless. Are you worried of shooting yourself in the foot? Then please don't use C++. At first you were concerned of beginners (?) misusing reserve, and now suddenly "the solution" is to use insert. This is a bit irritating. I'm sorry but I'm losing interest in this discussion. This has now become opinion based. Have a nice day!

Comment: There is a mountain of difference between `reserve+push_back` and ranged-`insert`, and that is `insert` correctly grows the capacity exponentially.

Answer (score 17):

```
vec.insert(std::end(vec),
           std::rbegin(array),
           std::rend(array));
```

Note that this uses C++14, but reverse iterators have been around much longer, you would just need to create them manually if stuck with an older standard:

```
int const a1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int a2[5];
std::copy(std::reverse_iterator<int const*>(std::end(a1)),
          std::reverse_iterator<int const*>(std::begin(a1)),
          std::begin(a2)); // copy in reverse

std::copy(std::begin(a2),
          std::end(a2),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // prints "5 4 3 2 1 "
```

Comment: `make_reverse_iterator(end(x)), make_reverse_iterator(begin(x))`

Comment: @Yakk `make_reverse_iterator` is also C++14, so doesn't help.

Comment: And `std::begin` is not C++03 either.

Comment: It's important to note that using single range insert is generally more efficient than `std::back_inserter` in selected answer.

Comment: @T.C. So what's wrong with that? Perfectly valid to have `NUL`s in a `std::string`, and I just wanted a simple example that allowed me to easily create an array and print the result.